# System.InvalidOperationException when reading values from xml file in C#

Tags: c#, xml

So i have this code sample... what it should do is... simple read a value from an xml file...

```
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(FileLoc);
    MessageBox.Show(xdoc.Descendants("energyPieces").First().Value);
```

But in the second line i ALWAYS get System.InvalidOperationException... WHILE the xml file IS valid: i checked it with a game(it's actually a game's save file) and checked it with multiple online checkers... Here is the XML file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Save xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DumaLegend">
  <saveInfo>
    <energyPieces>0</energyPieces>
    <fullEnergyCells>4</fullEnergyCells>
    <fullHearts>4</fullHearts>
    <globalSwitches xmlns:d3p1="a">
      <d3p1:switchList xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" />
    </globalSwitches>
    <gold>0</gold>
    <hasBigFireball>false</hasBigFireball>
    <hasCombo>false</hasCombo>
    <hasCrossbow>false</hasCrossbow>
    <hasDash>false</hasDash>
    <hasDashUpgrade>false</hasDashUpgrade>
    <hasDoubleJump>false</hasDoubleJump>
    <hasFireball>false</hasFireball>
    <hasHookshot>false</hasHookshot>
    <hasInvisPot>false</hasInvisPot>
    <hasSecondCombo>false</hasSecondCombo>
    <hasShieldUpgrade>false</hasShieldUpgrade>
    <hasSmallFireball>false</hasSmallFireball>
    <heartPieces>0</heartPieces>
    <heroPosOnMap>0</heroPosOnMap>
    <heroTokens>0</heroTokens>
    <itemSlot1 xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DumaLegend.Objects.Consumables" i:nil="true" />
    <itemSlot2 xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DumaLegend.Objects.Consumables" i:nil="true" />
    <lives>3</lives>
    <worldsUnlocked>0</worldsUnlocked>
    <worldsUnlockedOnMap>0</worldsUnlockedOnMap>
  </saveInfo>
  <saveSlot>0</saveSlot>
</Save>
```

Note: Sorry for copy-pasting it as html code I actually failed to put it in a code sample!

Edit: expected output: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a fully qualified name (i.e. including the namespace). Thus

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(FileLoc);
MessageBox.Show(xdoc.Descendants(XName.Get("energyPieces", "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DumaLegend")).First().Value);
```

or, if you prefer

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(FileLoc);
MessageBox.Show(xdoc.Descendants("{http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DumaLegend}energyPieces").First().Value);
```